# MongoDB: Dividing numbers which are of type string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to divide two numbers in MongoDB, but I have them in quotation marks.

I mean:

```
number1: "3"

number2: "25"
```

How can I divide them? Is there any possibility to divide number when they are in quotation marks?

I tried:

```
db.myproject.find({ $divide: [ "number1", "number2" ] })
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've MongoDB version > `4.0` - When you wanted to divide strings then you can convert those to numbers using an aggregation operator [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/index.html) & do your operation :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** '$addFields' will add new field to doc, if you just need 'dividedValue' field then use instead '$project' stage(with '_id:0') */
  {
    $addFields: {
      dividedValue: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: [ "$number2", "0" ]}, // When you divide by 0, '$divide' result in error so we're having conditional error check here
          "Can't divide by Zero",
          {
            $divide: [
              {
                $toInt: "$number1"
              },
              {
                $toInt: "$number2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/55E4xJvGr1w)